# Is there a word of reviewing something and suggesting ways to improve it?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Is there a word that means "reviewing" something and suggesting ways to "improve" it?

The only words I think of are "review" and "critique" however they only mean reviewing something but they don't suggest ways to improve it.

For example [word] my book. Is there a [word] that will review my book, tell me whether its good or bad and suggest ways to improve it.

**Update**: What about a website?

For example [word] my website. Is there a [word] that will review my website, tell me whether its good or bad and suggest ways to improve it.

Comment: Do you have a context? Otherwise "assessment" and "suggestion" might suit?

Answer (score 8):

I think ***[edit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/edit)*** is close to what you are referring to:

> - To prepare (written material) for publication or presentation, as by correcting, revising, or adapting.
> - (Journalism & Publishing) to prepare (text) for publication by checking and improving its accuracy, clarity, etc.

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

I think **critique** does suggest improvement.  For example, Kant's *Critique of Pure Reason* is not a criticism in the modern negative sense of the word, but an explanation of the ways reason has been misunderstood and misapplied, and a list of guidelines for avoiding those pitfalls.

Critque: "a detailed analysis and assessment of something, especially a literary, philosophical, or political theory."  ([Google's definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=critique))

Answer (score 2):

How about **constructive criticism**? From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_criticism):

> Constructive criticism is the process of offering valid and well-reasoned opinions about the work of others, usually involving both positive and negative comments, in a friendly manner rather than an oppositional one. The purpose of constructive criticism is to improve the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **Revise**.
It seems to have the sense you look for.

[Revise: to alter something already written or printed, in order to make corrections, improve, or update](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revise)

**Revising** and **editing** are separate processes but they may overlap and go hand in hand.

Comment: These sound too much like doing the actual improvement work, rather than giving advice.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context, consider ***proofreading***.

> proofread
>
> : *v.tr.* to read (copy or proof) in order to find errors and mark
> corrections.
>
> : *v.intr.* to read copy or proof for purposes of error
> detection and correction [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proofread)
>
> *Thank you, Aunt Judy, for taking the time to proofread my book* [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=IvbyIzwqQPcC&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=%22proofread+my+book+to%22&source=bl&ots=_kJ3DMjZU1&sig=DV9vwGqwx1BqtqqDGzwVggfO8bM&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAWoVChMI1uXToq-QyQIVRtgaCh1ckgIj#v=onepage&q=%22proofread%20my%20book%20to%22&f=false)
>
> *Proofread my website and provide annotated notes* [People Per Hour](https://www.peopleperhour.com/job/proofread-my-website-and-provide-annotated-notes-925433)

Answer (score 1):

For written material, consider **"copyedit"**:

> edit and correct (written or printed material)

([WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=copyedit&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=))

UPDATE: For website content (especially in the context of SEO), consider **"auditing"**:

> So, what is a content audit? A content audit is a careful look at your website’s existing content in order to make sure that it’s doing what you want it to do — driving the right kind of traffic, containing the right kind of keywords, and improving conversions.

(https://www.quicksprout.com/2014/04/24/how-to-conduct-a-content-audit-on-your-site/)

A content audit presupposes evaluation and further suggestions on how to improve things.